# Is it safe to left one branch of a Y-cable unplugged?

Tags: y-cable

I have an old synth that has single headphones output (but user manual states that it can be connected with line-level inputs). I also have an audio interface that has one combo Mic/Line mono input and one Hi-Z instrumental mono input.

Suppose that there is a Y-cable with single stereo jack on one side and two separate mono jacks on the other side. If I plug stereo end of the cable to the headphones output and plug one of the mono ends to line input of the audio interface while keeping the other branch of Y-cable unplugged, is it safe? By safety, I mean absence of damage to both the synth and the audio interface. For example, I found an information that using stereo cable for connecting stereo output to mono input may result in back-feeding and destroy of stereo output. And what about signal quality? Can a signal be distorted or corrupted with noise by this way of connecting things?

As an alternative, I also can plug the other branch of Y-cable to instrumental input. I guess that gain of this input must be set to very small level. If doing so, is it safe? Is it better or not in comparison with the previous idea?

Answer (score 1):

It would be interesting to know your source about the back-feed. A Google search shows me http://silentsky.net/wordpress/archives/624  where a back-feed happens when we use of an Y as a mixer. If the impedance of both outputs are too low, the current will have a too high intensity.

Here, the idea is completely different : you connect a channel of the headphones output to a line input of your audio interface, and you connect the other channel nowhere. There are no back-feed issue.

The main risk is that the unconnected channel act as an antenna. I don’t think it can destroy the associated output. The unconnected jack may also hit a ground which is not good… you have to be careful about it.

Note : there are two types of Y : splitters stereo-to-2xmono (ok here), and stereo to 2xstereo (typically to use 2 headphones when a single socket is available). They are not build equally. Edit : There is a third cable HOSA CMP-105 cable mono to stereo cited be the linked article which connect right and left which can damage systems if left/right **outputs** are shunted. I had never seen such a cable before. I guess the right use is to connect a mono output to a stereo input, and not the reverse.

Comment: Thanks for a detailed reply! As for back-feeding, I read about it there: https://www.pianodreamers.com/digital-piano-recording-guide/ in the section "Recording with a Headphone Output". Backfeeding is mentioned there not in context of mixing mono signals, but in context of connecting stereo output to mono input.

Comment: It is hard to believe the expression « stereo (balanced) cable ». stereo cable and balanced cable are two incompatible usage of a TRS jack. Back-feed is when left and right signals are short-circuited. This doesn’t apply with a splitter designed to separate right and left.

Comment: Let me clarify what I am talking about. Before I started to think about Y-cables, I used to think that stereo unbalanced jack to stereo unbalanced jack is a good way to connect headphones output of the synth to mono line input of the audio interface. Then I found the article I've referenced above. So, in the original question, example of back-feeding relates to a straight cable, not to a Y-cable. However, I am concerned with other possible issues that are specific to Y-cables. Because I am not experienced in sound recording, I asked are there any problems (not only back-feeding).

Comment: What you should avoid is to short-circuit an output (with an other output or with the ground). An Y cable (1 stereo - 2 mono) doesn’t do such a thing. The main risk is when the unconnected mono touch a ground connected surface. The recommandation “A simple mono-to-stereo cable or adapter is not recommended for this procedure. Doing so can damage your output device (digital piano).” is to prevent you to use some cables : 1stereo-1mono where each channel of the stereo are shunted in order to mix them and provides a mono signal. Some devices doesn’t like such a shunt (some other are more rugged).